# ListCreateAPIView: How can I cache a serialized QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF class with a single method `get_queryset()`. I would like to add caching to the serialized `queryset` by intercepting the request *before* `get_queryset` gets called, but after custom middleware/authentication has been run. Here is a trivial example of what I'm after:

```
class FooList(generics.ListCreateAPIView)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def intercept_for_caching(self):
        user = self.request.meta_data['user']
        cached_data = cache.get(f'FooStuff:{user.pk}')
        if cached_data:
            return Response(cached_data)
        else:
            new_data = ? # retrieve serialized queryset
            cache.set(f'FooStuff:{user.pk}', new_data)
            return Response(new_data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.meta_data['user']
        return Foo.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Are there any methods I can hook into?

I am aware that `cache_page` is designed for this use case (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/), but I haven't been able to get it to work with our custom middeleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33) has a function `list`:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I was able to cache the queryset by overriding `list`:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = self.request.user
    cache = caches['redis']
    cache_key = f'my_cache:{user.pk}'
    cached_results = cache.get(cache_key)
    if cached_results:
        return Response(cached_results)
    else:
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        cache.set(cache_key, serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```